# Gstreamer pipeline with output selector does not start

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I created a pipeline where the source is always running, but I want to disable the output under conditions. As suggested in another thead i used an output-selector, so that I have the following pipeline
[image: Pipeline]

When I change pipeline status to "playing" I can see only the first frame. From the pipeline graph it seems to me that fakesink is not able to switch to "ready" state, but I do not understand why. Can someone help me with this?

Minimal code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool running = true;

    gst_init(&argc,&argv);

    GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("main-pipeline");
    GstElement* source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc","mysource");
    GstElement* selector = gst_element_factory_make("output-selector","myselector");
    GstElement* realsink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink","realsink");
    GstElement* fakesink = gst_element_factory_make("fakesink","fakesink");

    GstPad* osel_src1 = gst_element_get_request_pad(selector, "src_%u");
    GstPad* osel_src2 = gst_element_get_request_pad(selector, "src_%u");
    GstPad* realsinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(realsink, "sink");
    GstPad* fakesinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(fakesink, "sink");

    if(pipeline == NULL ||
       source == NULL ||
       selector == NULL ||
       realsink == NULL ||
       fakesink == NULL ||
       osel_src1 == NULL ||
       osel_src2 == NULL ||
       realsinkpad == NULL ||
       fakesinkpad == NULL)
    {
        g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source , selector, realsink, fakesink, NULL);

    if ((gst_element_link(source, selector) != TRUE) ||
        (gst_pad_link(osel_src1, fakesinkpad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) ||
        (gst_pad_link(osel_src2, realsinkpad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) )
    {
        g_printerr("Failed linking.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (selector), "active-pad", osel_src2, NULL);

    /* Start playing */
    GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if(ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    std::thread pipelineThread = std::thread( [&] { 
        GstBus *bus;
        GstMessage *msg;

        /* Wait until error or EOS */
        bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
        while(running)
        {
            msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, 100 * GST_MSECOND, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

            if (msg != NULL)
                gst_message_unref (msg);
        }

        gst_object_unref (bus);
     } );

    sleep(1);

    GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE((GstBin*)pipeline, GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "pipeline");

    std::cin.get();
    running = false;

    if(pipelineThread.joinable())
        pipelineThread.join();

    /* Free resources */
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about using `tee` element, splitting into two branches/sinks, and restricting the output at one sink using element `identity`or `valve` ? I have never worked with `output-selector`, but I am sure the one with `tee` & `identity` will work.

Comment: Perhaps the selector behaves similar to a tee? Then you would need a `queue` after all output pads from the selector.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, no, it doesn't seem to help...

Comment: @VenkateshKuppan, not sure what do you mean: where should i put the tee? I tried with a configuration like videotestsrc->valve->autovideosink, and everything started correctly. After a couple of second I switched property drop to true, the video freezed. But after a few second again I switched again drop to false, and the video still freezes.

Comment: The `valve` element has an issue with replaying the video once it's paused. There is already a bug raised by me in the GStreamer gnome system. But as an alternative , you can use element `identity` and toggle the property `drop-probability` as per your requirements.  Place a `tee`, instead of `output-selector` that splits your output. But in this case, both the branches will be active all the time. Ofcourse you can restrict one output using the `identity` as I mentioned, but in reality both the branches of tee will be active. You must analyse your system requirements if you can afford this.

Comment: Here is an example of using [tee](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html)